# Unable to log into Windows 7 PC - "The RPC server is unavailable"

Tags: windows-7, login, services

I am trying to log into my Windows 7 computer and after entering in my username and password (which I have confirmed is correct), I am seeing the error message "The RPC server is unavailable".

I have tried booting up in Safe mode but it doesn't help.

I think this is caused by some sort of registry corruption, but I'm not sure how to fix it if I cannot log in.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: To start the RPC service, try these steps.

a. Start the computer using Windows DVD to boot to Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE) and select command prompt.

b. Type net start RpcSs and hit enter.

c. Type exit to close the command prompt.

d. Restart the computer and check the result.

Step 2: Check the registry entry for the service

a. Start the computer using Windows DVD to boot to Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE) and select command prompt.

b. On the command prompt, type regedit.exe and hit enter.

c. Look for the following entries:

d. Entry for Remote Procedure Call (RPC): Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\RpcSs

e. Entry for Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\RpcLocator

Important: 
Set REG_DWORD value to 2 for automatic start on RpcSs
Set REG_DWORD value to 3 for manual start on RPCLocator

Very important: Modifying the registry incorrectly will cause serious damage to the computer. Backup the registry before you make any changes.

Reference: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7repair/thread/734dc03b-a795-4f08-aa32-84cf12b5e6be