# Windows 7 login error "The RPC server is unavailable."

Tags: windows-7, login-screen

As the title reads, I'm unable to log into my Windows 7 because I'm receiving the error "The RPC server is unavailable." when I type in my password.

As such the solution on the following thread won't work.
[Unable to log into Windows 7 PC - "The RPC server is unavailable"](https://superuser.com/questions/203733/unable-to-log-into-windows-7-pc-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable)

I tried to use Windows 7 boot media to resolve it, but it couldn't. Is there a way I can resolve this?